# Add HTML code into AEM component programmatically

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

I need to add a html comment on every AEM component that I add to a page. Anyone knows how can this be done?

I want to do something like this:

```
<!-- comment added -->
< html component>

</ html component>
<!-- comment added -->
```

Comment: You want to add comment only for those components that are dragged and dropped from sidekick or for all the components that are present on the page ?

Comment: Only for the dragged and dropped

Comment: I'm doing some automatic Tests so I want to add a html comment on every dragged component in order to locate them

Comment: Why dont you add this comment in your component itself so that where ever this component is dropped, this comment will be rendered? or am i missing something ?

Comment: @MohitBansal we are trying to create the tests in different AEM/CQ projects so we cannot add this comment on the components because the tests are not on the same project and we have no access to that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `cq:listeners`. This is used to capture various events in the lifecycle of a component. There is a listener `afterinsert` which is fired on inserting a component on a page. Create a handler script for this event which you can use to add comments into the DOM (e.g. before the component div). Jquery can easily help you with this as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VHQ9F/).

And `afterdelete` listener can be used to remove that comment from the DOM.

More details on listeners [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/components/edit_config.html#cq:listeners).